# Is there any way that I can refresh the page after downloading an excel file from same page in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Is there any possible way that I can refresh my page after downloading an excel file from same page in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reload your page,

```
Response.redirect("your page");
```

Comment: Yes I tried Resonse.Redirect. It redirects my page but excel file doesn't get download.

Comment: you can use after downloading excel file.